# what's the solution for using blade in javascript callback functions?

Tags: javascript, parsing, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an AJAX query to server, the server returns some data then in the callback function I have a `resultStr` to be put in the target `<div>`. The `resultStr` gets iterated for the lenght of the object and iterates over all the data I need to show. The point is Blade doesn’t parse the syntax if you move the JavaScript to a separate file in assets so the data doesn’t show. Some say: put the variables in the PHP view and then set them in the JavaScript. That’s not good as for example CSRF token becomes visible in the view in the source. Also it doesn’t work at all for iterating over data. Let’s say in my view I passed some data like:

```
'items' => $items
```

Then I need to fill the page after the AJAX call with all the `$items`.
The `resultStr` in the callback function has something like:

```
"foreach ($items as $i)" +

"<option value=\"{{ $item->id }}\">{{ ($item->name) }}</option>"
```

As Blade is not parsing the result string it simply will not work and I can’t declare those variables (`$items` and `$i`) in the PHP part. It makes no sense and if I try to do all I get is `undefined variable`.

So, what is the solution to make Blade parse the `resultStr` and have the JavaScript in separate file?

updated after reply, here I am trying to separate the script from the result string which I load from an external file but the result is not good.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('form');
        form.submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: form.prop('action'),
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (data) {

                    var obj = (data);
                    var results = "";
                    var filler;
                    $.ajax('js/blade/filler.blade.php', {
                        dataType: 'text',
                        success: function (data) {
                            filler = data;
                            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                                results = results + filler;

                                $("#results").html(results);

                            }

                        }
                    });

                }

            })
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: You can’t parse Blade templates in JavaScript, as the Blade compiler takes the template string and parses things like variables and control structures (`@foreach` etc). You’ll need to do this server-side.

Comment: Also: “That’s not good as for example CSRF token becomes visible in the view in the source.” Your CSRF token is visible to _anyone_ who views the source of your Laravel application any way. It’s not a secret token, it’s just meant to stop people posting form data to your application from other sites.

Comment: "You can’t parse Blade templates in JavaScript", blade syntax gets parsed if you leave the script in the view, what I want to achieve is separate the script from the view. My script returns a resultStr which contains blade syntax. I tried like this: separate the script in script.js and a resultStr.blade.php then have the script load the resultStr.blade.php and put into the string but doesn't work either. Please see updated post

Comment: @MartinBeanwhat do you mean I need to do this server side? How?

Comment: @MartinBean another solution could be forget blade in the resultstr and use plain php, right?

Comment: You can’t parse PHP via AJAX. PHP needs to be parsed by a server.

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinBean says, you can't parse blade on Javascript, because it's php, and you cant execute php directly via Javascript, it's a server side language.

An approach could be doing an ajax request to a view that has something like this:

```
<?php
echo json_encode($items);
```

And then, in the ajax function you can use something like this:

```
var form = $('form');
var display_div = $('#display_div');
form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr( 'action' ), // <form action="site.com/some-view">
        data: form.serialize(),
        type: 'post'
    }).done(function (data) {
        var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(parsed_data,function(key,value)
        {
           display_div.append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

I recommend you do all the logic in that ajax request if possible, to get everything in just one.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the question: I moved all the variables generation and stuff to the controller. Now when I submit the form all the needed data is passed to jquery in the object and then used to generate the resultStr. The error was passing some variables to the form page and then trying to use those after the submit.